# how to differentiate onmessage of websocket

Tags: websocket

Right now I'm working on app in which data is send from server to client using WEB SOCKET . But How should I differentiate onMessage() event to accept different data from Server.Anyway to do it ?

Comment: Please define "different data". In what way is some data different from the other?

Comment: different data means ..A new data I want to send to another page..A new JSON...

Comment: Sorry, but you don't make much sense. You were talking about the server sending data to the client, and now you are talking about data you are sending to another page?

Comment: @Philipp..Yes Server Sending data to client..Client having websocket connection..on which he listen...I want to make client listen different responses..

Comment: @Abhijit Muke, I too am not sure what you mean by "differentiate onMessage() event" but I'm going to assume that you're asking how a client should parse data sent from the server to know what to do with it. If that's what you mean, then the answer is, it's your choice how to format the data. If you want to use JSON as the messaging format, then the property name of the stringified object could be something that you test for on the client end. For example, you could send string data like {"start":"some-data"} or {"close":"other-data"}, and test for evt.data.start, etc. on the client end.

Comment: @HartleySan..Thanks For Solution...But this thing I don't have to do..coz data from server is coming so Fast if I handle this way then my speed is getting slow...That's why I'm searching for other technique to parse it.Thanking you